# copy /move the Data from the Linux Command line to local windows

Tags: linux, scp, winscp, pscp

Installed CYGWIN in my windows, I can able to access both windows & remote linux machines with the credentials. But i can't able to configure how the data will be moved from Linux to windows, can anyone please suggest me on this.

Thanks
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log into your cygwin instance remotely, you need to install the sshd module in cygwin and then set it up.  Then you will be able to use the ssh command on your linux/unix machine to do one of many things:

open a bash shell in your cygwin instance
execute a remote command from linux/unix using: ssh WINDOWS_SERVER command
copy to the Windows machine remotely using scp or sftp.